# Highchart xAxis.currentDateIndicator showing the current time (passing by)

Tags: highcharts

currentDateIndicator seems to only show time of loading the chart. Also currentDateIndicator.label.formatter is called only once (on load).

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: [{
    id: 'bottom-datetime-axis',
    currentDateIndicator: {
        label: {
            format: '%Y-%M-%d, %H:%M:%S',
            formatter: function(indicator) {
                console.log("currentDateIndicator"); // this is called just once (on load)
                return indicator;
            },                
        }
    },
```

How to make currentDateIndicator dynamic showing the current time passing by?

https://jsfiddle.net/ft2ubchk/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to update x-axis every second, for example:

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function(){
                var xAxis = this.xAxis[0];
                setInterval(function(){
                    xAxis.update({});
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/eh5zp36o/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update